# Convert a column dataframe into list and read the first element

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this

**dataframe**

```
name          address

Wings        3109 N Main St, Hope Mills, NC 28348   
Burger King  407 N Eastern Blvd, Fayetteville, NC 28301
```

I am trying to convert the column address into a list to be able to get the fist element of each row: 3109 N Main St and 407 N Eastern Blvd

So far this is my code

```
df = pd.read_csv("mydataframe.csv")
df['address'] = list(df['address'])
df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df.address.map(lambda x: x[0])
```

With this code I am getting the new_colum but I am getting the first character of the column address

```
name          address                                   new_col

Wings        3109 N Main St, Hope Mills, NC 28348          3
Burger King  407 N Eastern Blvd, Fayetteville, NC 28301    4
```

Expected Output

```
name          address                                   new_col

Wings        3109 N Main St, Hope Mills, NC 28348          3109 N Main St
Burger King  407 N Eastern Blvd, Fayetteville, NC 28301    407 N Eastern Blvd
```

Comment: added a solution, does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['new_col'] = df['address'].str.split(',',1).str[0]
df
```

```
    name            address                                     new_col
0   Wings           3109 N Main St, Hope Mills, NC 28348        3109 N Main St
1   Burger King     407 N Eastern Blvd, Fayetteville, NC 28301  407 N Eastern Blvd
```